# Define Constants in Gradle in Java Project

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, spring-boot

I am building a Spring Boot project and i want to define some constants in gradle. I used to be an Android developer, and in Android you can define it with `buildConfigField`. How can I do it in Java project?

Is there a tool that is equivalent to the following?

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "http://debug.server.com"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "http://release.server.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805846/how-do-you-specify-buildconfigfield-in-gradle-java-library-project-build-script

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you are using **Gradle** as your building tool, you can define Environment Variables inside you **build.gradle** file, using the following syntax:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        if (System.getenv("RESOLVE_LOCAL")) {
            maven { url "$indexUrl/resolver-grails3" }
        } else {
            maven { url "$indexLocalUrl/resolver-grails3" }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'build-info-extractor:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath group: 'org._10ne.gradle', name: 'rest-gradle-plugin, version: '0.3.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.10ne.rest'
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. The question appears to be asking how to vary the value of a Java constant named "BASE_URL." This answer appears to be showing how to vary what Maven repository Gradle uses.

Comment: Environment variables is not the same as compile-time constants. Environment variables may be changed by... well... the environment.