# How do you specify buildConfigField in Gradle Java-library Project build script

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processor

Within my Android projects I can specify Gradle constants as follows:

```
buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'analyticsEnabled', 'false'
```

and access them in my Android application like this:-

```
public boolean isAnalyticsEnabled() {
        return BuildConfig.analyticsEnabled;
}
```

How can I get the same functionality within a Java library Gradle build script?

To be more precise, I am developing a custom annotation processor as a pure Java project (library) that my Android application is dependant on.

I would like to define constants within my Java Gradle build file that are accessible by my annotation processor.

If this is possible, then how to I achieve it?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm using a Java library module as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of [these plugins](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=buildconfig). E.g. [`de.fuerstenau.buildconfig`](https://github.com/mfuerstenau/gradle-buildconfig-plugin):

*`build.gradle`*:

```
plugins {
    id 'de.fuerstenau.buildconfig' version '1.1.8'
}

buildConfig {
    buildConfigField 'String', 'QUESTION', '"Life, The Universe, and Everything"'
    buildConfigField 'int', 'ANSWER', '42'
}
```

And then get a `BuildConfig` class like:

```
public final class BuildConfig
{
    private BuildConfig () { /*. no instance */ }

    public static final String VERSION = "unspecified";
    public static final String NAME = "DemoProject";

    public static final String QUESTION = "Life, The Universe, and Everything";
    public static final int ANSWER = 42;
}
```

If you're using Kotlin and want to generate a Kotlin version `BuildConfig` take a look at [`io.pixeloutlaw.gradle.buildconfigkt`](https://github.com/PixelOutlaw/buildconfig-gradle-plugin) as well.

If don't like that idea, what you can do is resource filtering:

*`build.gradle`*:

```
processResources {
    expand project.properties
}
```

*`gradle.properties`* (these values are the same as `project.question` and `project.answer`):

```
question=Life, The Universe, and Everything
answer=42
```

*`src/main/resources/buildconfig.properties`*:

```
question=${question}
answer=${answer}
```

Then just read `buildconfig.properties` into `Properties` in your app and use the values.